# HTTP Status [403]. Spring MVC and Apache Tomcat 8.5.15

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-security

My problem is about refuses to authorize it. This problem I had got when I deployed my WAR file on the server. I can log in but I can't go forward to the user panel where access have just `ROLE_USER` or `ROLE_ADMIN`. I tested my application with `localhost` and I hadn't problems with authorization. I imported the whole database from local to server datebase (I'm using MySQL).

Here is the error:

[image]

Here is my code:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = UserDetailsServiceImpl.class)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/homepage")
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/homepage")
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    } 
}

@Controller
@Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN"})
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin")
public class AdminController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private UserRoleService userRoleService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String start(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("username", SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
        model.addAttribute("userlist", userService.getListOfUsers());
        return "admin/start";
    }
}

@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userDAO.findByUsername(username);
        if (user != null) {
            boolean enabled = user.getStatus().equals(UserStatus.ACTIVE);
            boolean accountNonExpired = user.getStatus().equals(UserStatus.ACTIVE);
            boolean credientialsNonExpired = user.getStatus().equals(UserStatus.ACTIVE);
            boolean accountNonLocker = user.getStatus().equals(UserStatus.ACTIVE);

            Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

            for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole()));
            }

            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(),
                user.getPassword(),
                enabled,
                accountNonExpired,
                credientialsNonExpired,
                accountNonLocker,
                authorities);
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("User not found:  %1$d", username));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you update the question with info what exactly is sent when you call it (request, headers etc) as well as show which exact roles added (is it `USER` or `ROLE_USER`?)?

Comment: Ok, I updated, in database i have 'ROLE_USER'

Comment: if i'm logged by admin i call http://www.example.com:8080/flashcard/admin

Comment: Could you please add Spring Security logs (with level `DEBUG` enabled in your log configuration) to your question. It will show, the reason for 403.